# CSS Animation Is Not Working In Firefox Browser

Tags: html, css, animation

I'm trying to make a simple text animation for my friend's project & the animation is perfectly working on Chrome & MS Edge Browser but it's not getting compatible with Firefox while I have used the -moz-background-clip

If anyone can help me with this it would be great for me.

Thank

```css
.my-name {
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 2em;
    letter-spacing: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, white, white, white, rgb(29, 29, 29));
    background-repeat: round;
    background-size: 80%;
    animation: animate-my-name 5s linear infinite;
    background-clip: text;
    -webkit-background-clip: text; 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    -moz-background-clip: text;
    -moz-text-fill-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
}
@keyframes animate-my-name {
    0% {
    background-position: -500%;
    }
    100% {
    background-position: 500%;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1 class="my-name">HELLO WORLD</h1>
```

you

Comment: Seems to work if `background-repeat: round` is removed. Not a clue why to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

In order to use the `@keyframes` method, you need to use the `animation` property/properties. `animation` property is a shorthand.
To make it easier, few of the properties might help for such an animation:
`animation-duration` - Specify the duration of the animations (ex. 1s or 750ms) [REQUIRED]
`animation-name` - The name, over here since you have used `animate-my-name`, the value here would be `animate-my-name, must be similar to the` @keyframes`identifier.`animation-iteration-count`- Count of animations,`infinite`for infinite.`animation-direction` - Pattern, for example, reverse to oppose the animation and alternate to reverse in an even repetition.

For more properties: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp